# How to create an OpenGL live wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, mobile, live-wallpaper

I'm trying to find the right approach for creating an Android OpenGL live wallpaper i.e. a way to convert an app written to use GLSurfaceView into a live wallpaper. There appears to be nothing in the official Android documentation about this surprisingly and it's not obvious what to do.

I've found a few discussions about this elsewhere where most end up linking to the following code written an Android developer:
http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers

However, the comments on the page suggest there are problems with the code (memory leaks, lock ups). Does anyone know of any alternatives? If I upload a wallpaper to the market, I'd obviously like to avoid complaints caused by buggy code.

Comment: I imagine this is a very good way to kill your battery

Comment: Not really. Live wallpapers only run when your screen is on and you're at the homescreen. Efficient live wallpapers use <5% of your overall battery life. Using the GPU can save battery too.

Answer (score 3):

I found an open source example that may help you.
http://code.google.com/p/android-deep-wallpaper/

also, it looks like to use open GL, the GL ES code needs to be called from a different thread.

hope this helps :D

Comment: it looks like or it is ? Please confirm so other user can not have wrong implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for building OpenGL Live Wallpapers for Android called GLWallpaperService. You can find [GLWallpaperService on GitHub](https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService). It includes the code you linked to on rbgrn.net but with a few bug fixes included. There are some alternate implementations available as well. Good luck.